# Optional at end of regular expression

Tags: regex

Folks, I have the following data:

Valid Data:

```
08902-00243
08902-00243-1
08902-00243-12
```

Invalid Data:

```
08902-002
cat
08902-00243-844
08902-0024A-
08902-0024A-45
08902-00243-
```

I am trying to create a regular expression to validate the above data:

```
\d{5}-\d{5}-\d{2}?
```

However I cannot get the optional (?) to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the rule? in what language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below regex

```
^(\d{5}-\d{5}(-\d\d?)?)$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/nA5mD3/4)

Comment: Sounds Good, You're welcome. If the problem is solved then accept the best answer and close the thread be clicking green mark tick.

Comment: Can you please check this, there is one combination that should be invalid: 08902-00245-

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a `-` and also have a range to account for 1 digit in the last group.

```
echo "08902-00243-12" | egrep -o "\d{5}-\d{5}(-\d{1,2})?$"
```

Comment: but as per demo as linked in my post its  not working for `08902-00243-844`

Comment: Thanks.  Can you check 08902-00243-844

Comment: Added a $ to indicate the end of the range

Comment: @BenWhaley might then also add `^` for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the last - into the optional as well:
`\d{5}-\d{5}(-\d{1,2})?`

Comment: @Braj after a firm edit to account for allowed "-\d" at the end, yes, it all works fine.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you check 08902-00243-844

Comment: @Braj This is not allowed by the OP and not allowed by this RegEx, since we use `\d{1,2}` at the end.